# font or tikz to draw tally counting symbols (///)

Tags: tikz-pgf, fonts, symbols

In a book I have the following to illustrate the traditional counting symbols used for hand tallying.  They were drawn using PPT and saved in a PNG image, but look ugly and when I try to use one in inline text, I can't get the image properly centered over the baseline.

Is there any font for this, or a way to do this with tikz?

[image]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/102065 has several solutions.

Comment: The comprehensive symbols list shows `hhcount` package to be closest to this, but the package isn't on CTAN any longer, apparently

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\TCS}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,#1]
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(mod(\X,5))}]in {1,...,#2}
{\ifnum\Y=0
\draw (\X*0.5ex+0.3ex,0) -- ++(-2.8ex,2ex);
\else
\draw (\X*0.5ex+0.3ex,0) -- ++(-0.3ex,2ex);
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
abc \TCS{3}\ def \TCS{7}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or slanted to the right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\TCS}[2][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,#1]
\foreach \X [evaluate=\X as \Y using {int(mod(\X,5))}]in {1,...,#2}
{\ifnum\Y=0
\draw (\X*0.5ex+0.3ex,0) -- ++(-2.2ex,1.8ex);
\else
\draw (\X*0.5ex+0.3ex,0) -- ++(0.3ex,1.8ex);
\fi}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
abc \TCS{3}\ def \TCS{7}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The additional optional key is to enable things like `abc \TCS[red]{3}\ def \TCS[blue,thick]{7}`.

Answer (score 9):

A different approach with `bullcntr`, that shows 'unusual' tally symbols: bullets!

But the number of symbols is limited to `9`, so the symbols repeat.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{bullcntr}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcounter{bull}
\newcommand{\showbullcntr}[1]{%
  \setcounter{bull}{#1}%
  \bullcntr{bull}%
}
\begin{document}



\foreach \x in {1,...,200} {
  \pgfmathmod{\x}{5}
  \pgfmathint{\pgfmathresult}
  \edef\y{\pgfmathresult}
  \typeout{Current: \x and \y}
  \showbullcntr{\y}\ 
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to catch the hidden message in that pattern...

Comment: It is not so hidden: "2019 will be a good year for being nice to marmots." ;-)

Comment: @marmot: No, it says: Don't mess up with people from Black Forest ;-)

Comment: I can't believe it: someone has actually made use of the `bullcntr` package!  I was thinking it was time to withdraw it...

Comment: @GuM: I wanted to transport hidden messages with the `bullcntr` patterns ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Using a macro and `cancel` package to definite a cut symbol. With `mskip-4mu` you can decrease or increase the space between the `\slash`s.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{cancel}
\newcommand{\thbacks}{\slash\mskip-4mu\slash\mskip-4mu\slash\mskip-4mu\slash}
\begin{document}
\[\slash, \quad \slash\slash, \quad \slash\slash\slash, \quad \bcancel{\thbacks}\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Direct from the documentation of `gmp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shellescape]{gmp}

\newcommand{\scratchcount}[1]{%
  \begin{mpost}
  n:=#1;
  height := 3/5\mpdim{\baselineskip} ;
  span := 1/3 * height ;
  drift := 1/10 * height ;
  pickup pencircle scaled (1/12 * height) ;
  def d = (uniformdeviate drift) enddef ;
  for i := 1 upto n :
    draw
      if (i mod 5)=0 : ((-d-4.5span,d)--(+d-0.5span,height-d))
      else : ((-d,+d)--(+d,height-d)) fi
      shifted (span*i,d-drift) ;
  endfor;
  picture cp ;
  cp := currentpicture ; %for readability
  setbounds currentpicture to
    (llcorner cp shifted (0,-ypart llcorner cp) --
     lrcorner cp shifted (0,-ypart lrcorner cp) --
     urcorner cp -- ulcorner cp -- cycle) ;
  \end{mpost}}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{scratchenum}
 {\begin{enumerate} \@namedef{label\@enumctr}{\scratchcount{\arabic{\@enumctr}}}}
 {\end{enumerate}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{scratchenum}
\item Cinque \scratchcount{5}
\item Dieci \scratchcount{10}
\item Venti \scratchcount{20}
\item Trenta \scratchcount{30}
\item Trentasei \scratchcount{36}
\item Quarantatré \scratchcount{43}
\end{scratchenum}

\end{document}
```

The numbers are what Figaro sings at the beginning of *Le nozze di Figaro*, by Mozart and Da Ponte. Note that the tally marks are drawn with a certain degree of randomness.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The necessary files for the example below are available from http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/usergrps/uktug/baskervi/5_5/hhcount.sty and http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/usergrps/uktug/baskervi/5_5/hhutils0.sty

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hhcount}

\begin{document}
\fcscore{42}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adobe offers a free font supporting both Western and ideographic tally marks:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TallyMarks-Regular.otf}% https://github.com/adobe-fonts/tally-marks
\begin{document}
%%% Western tally marks
 % U+1D377







 % U+1D378



%%% Ideographic tally marks
 % U+1D372

 % U+1D373

 % U+1D374

 % U+1D3785

 % U+1D376
\end{document}
```

[image: output]